# Akka actor won't reconnect to remote Actor after restart

Tags: java, docker, akka

So I have 2 dockers that run 2 akka systems.

Container A runs System A

Container B runs System B

When System A loads, it connects to System B with:

```
Await.result(system.actorSelection(actorPath).resolveOne(new Timeout(RESOLVE_DURATION)), RESOLVE_DURATION)
```

all good here, the connection is a success and the systems exchange messages.

Then I restart Container B

```
docker restart container-b
```

On System A, I added a watch on System B if its terminated.
when I restart System B, I get akka Terminated message in System A - All good.
Then I start a reconnection loop each 5 seconds and try to reconnect to system B again with:

```
Await.result(system.actorSelection(actorPath).resolveOne(new Timeout(RESOLVE_DURATION)), RESOLVE_DURATION)
```

but now, I get a exceptions that ActorNotFound.

```
    [ERROR] [21/08/2017 08:11:49.851] [exchange-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] [akka.remote.EndpointWriter] AssociationError [akka.tcp://system@systemA:2555] -> [akka.tcp://system@systemB:2550]: Error [Shut down address: akka.tcp://system@systemB:2550] [
    akka.remote.ShutDownAssociation: Shut down address: akka.tcp://system@systemB:2550
    Caused by: akka.remote.transport.Transport$InvalidAssociationException: The remote system terminated the association because it is shutting down.
    ]

    [ERROR] [21/08/2017 08:11:54.850] [exchange-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] [c.m.e.c.actors.watchdog.WatchDog] Failed to reconnect to path [akka.tcp://system@systemB:2550/user/MyActor]
    akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://system@systemB:2550/), Path(/user/MyActor)]
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:65) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:63) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:73) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:74) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:120) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.execute(Future.scala:73) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:345) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.EmptyLocalActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:553) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.DeadLetterA

ctorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:589) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:579) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef.$bang(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:85) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.remote.EndpointManager$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(Remoting.scala:614) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.remote.EndpointManager.aroundReceive(Remoting.scala:400) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:525) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:494) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at 
scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
```

**the actorPath in the first connections is the same path when I try to reconnect.**

Only when I restart system A (by restarting the Container A), the connection is a success just like in the beginning.

**Versions:**

java 8

akka version : 2.4.0

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:07:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:07:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

**EDIT:**
Im running Simple remote, not a akka cluster
+
This is my conf:

```
akka {        
  provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = ${?AKKA_HOST}
      port = ${?AKKA_PORT}

      bind-hostname = 0.0.0.0
    }
  }
}
```

This conf works and messages are been transferd between the to containers

Comment: Are you running an Akka cluster? Or simple remoting?

Comment: Added EDIT to the post

Comment: I see. One more clarification needed: what do you mean by "restart system B" in "Only when I restart system B, the connection is a success just like in the beginning"? I supposed restarting the container means that the actor system is restarted inside it as well.

Comment: Damn, sorry. I meant to say when I restart system A!
so, I restart the container of System A (=Docker A), then the connection to system B passes

Comment: I just ran a little test using a slightly modified version of https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/tree/2.5/akka-sample-remote-scala (although locally, without docker). It does pretty much the same what you're doing, I've only added reconnection in Terminated message handler. It successfully resumed message exchange after receiver was brought back. Perhaps take a look at that sample and see if it works for you. Also, you're using a very outdated Akka version, there could be some related bugs, try updating to 2.4.20 or 2.5.4.

Comment: When I ran my code locally it also works.


I think it maybe something related when im using docker

Ill try to update akka to 2.5.4, will post on results

Comment: thanks @VasiliyIvashin
it worked with 2.5.4